# CakePHP webroot and tmp folders hacked

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a project. Project has two parts:

- portal (WordPress)
- Admin (CakePHP 3.*)

I have faced a problem on my production site. My project had hacked, some one add some files in mostly every folder of portal (WordPress) and webroot and /tmp folder of admin (Cakephp).

For now, Currently I have removed root folder and take pull from branch master. Problem was resolved but I know this is not a permanent solution.

Folder Structure is like this:

```
<root>
    admin (cakePHP)
    wp-admin
    wp-content
    wp-includes 
    index.php
    wp-config.php
    ....
    .... and other word press files
```

Why this issue occurred and what are the solutions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you determined whether WP or the Cake app was your point of vulnerability? Were you keeping up to date with WP and Composer updates? Is Cake 3 still in support? What is the strength of your FTP/SSH passwords?

Comment: As most of case, i guess is corrupted WP installation targeted by bot who scan vulnerability and upload backdoor what ever he is allow to put.

Comment: **[serverfault: How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)** Please note that such questions are usually considered offtopic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Secure your both section wordpress and cakephp.

1) Cakephp security - https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html

2) Wordpress security - https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/secure-your-wordpress-website/

3) Change ftp username and password make more secure

4) Check with server has firewall installed or not.

Comment: Thanks these links are helpful

Answer (score 1):

Actually you facing question who concern many things, let split it in couple of topic.

1/ WP

- Keep your install always up to date.
- Remove unused plugins.
- keep updated plugins and change it if is not from trusted source.
- Keep updated theme and change it if is not from trusted source.
- Remove wordpress version number, and if possible all things on your html who help to identify wordpress/theme/plugin.
- Because your install are already corrupted, change all credentials.

2/ your cakePHP

- Check if you escape all SQL queries
- Check if you have relevant security when you allow user to upload file (mimetype, extention, rename file, don't allow Webserver to execute PHP or Perl or Python inside your uploads folder)
- Because your install are already corrupted, change all credentials.

3/ Server structure

- You should not allow server side script execution inside wordpress and CakePHP uploads folder.
- You should keep as distinct folder and Unix user your both installation to prevent 1 who allow to affect the other one.
- Because your install are already corrupted, change all credentials.